# javascript create dynamic html function?

Tags: javascript, html

Im making a program that dynamically creates html elements and when you click any of those elements it should display its value in another textbox. This is the class im using to define the element:

```js
class msg_element{
  constructor(msg){
    this.message = msg;

    this.element = document.createElement("P");
    this.element.innerHTML = this.message;
    this.element.addEventListener("click", function(){
      document.getElementById("update").value = this.message;
    });

    document.getElementById("textview").appendChild(this.element);
  }
}
```

and this is the loop that creates the elements:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < bmg_msg.length; i++){
    var element = new msg_element(bmg_msg[i]);
  }
```

it creates all the elements correctly, but the clicking function doesnt work, it just displays "undefined" in the textbox. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: can you show complete example of your code including html js and css?

Comment: The value of `this` inside the event listener won't be the same as `this` in the constructor function. You could use an `=>` function instead of a regular function, or you could explicitly store `this` in a separate local variable in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
    this.element.addEventListener("click", function(){
      document.getElementById("update").value = this.message;
    });
```

is the problem.
When you create the callback you define it as `function(){...}`. The problem with that is that it causes `this` to refer to the event target. To fix this you can either:

Use an **Arrow function** so that `this` will refer to the current class instance.

```js
    this.element.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
      document.getElementById("update").value = this.message;
    });
```

or create a variable to store the reference to the constructor

```js
    let _this = this;
    this.element.addEventListener("click", function(){
      document.getElementById("update").value = _this.message;
    });
```

Comment: `this` never refers to the function itself. In an event listener, it's the same as the event target.

Comment: *"either do"* I'd expand on this textually.

Comment: *"lambda function"* ? You mean **Arrow function**

Comment: PS, don't forget that `Class` is just syntactic sugar for prototypal inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

In this portion of your code:

```
this.element.addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("update").value = this.message;
});
```

Beware: `this` outside of the click handler is different from `this` inside of it.

Inside event handlers, `this` always points to the DOM element that fired the event (in your case it's the paragraph you're creating).

A possible fix would be to use a variable which will hold the value of `this.message`, e.g.:

```
var myMessage = this.message;
this.element.addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("update").value = myMessage;
});
```

Comment: *" `this` always points to the DOM element that fired the event"* is not entirely true, it depends on the context of `this`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan What do you mean? In what cases does it not point to the event target?